# A service runs inside a pod in the pod’s network

Tags: kubernetes

[This](https://getenroute.io/blog/ingress-controller-kubernetes-api-gateway-secure-service-jwt-oauth-oidc-network-namespace/) document states that:

"A service runs inside a pod in the pod’s network".

It also states that:

"A service resides in a pod or several pods"

Is that a contradiction or is it true?

I have always thought of a services is it own entity, and just a distributed iptables setting, that points to pods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true in a sense. I think the term service leads to some confusion here. You are referring to the Kubernetes `service configuration object`, which does not "run" anywhere. Kubernetes uses it for configuring iptables and stuff on the Kubernetes nodes as you say. It is just a configuration. The article is talking about the `service implementation`, which runs in one or more pods.